# When does the forgetful functor S-Mod -> R-Mod induce injective maps on Ext-groups?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

Assume we have a complete regular local ring $R$ and an $R$-algebra $S$.

Is there a class of such algebras $S$ with the following property:

Given two $S$-modules $M,N$, then the maps induced by the forgetful functor $S-Mod \rightarrow R-Mod$ give injections $Ext^i_S(M,N)\rightarrow Ext_R^i(M,N)$?

If this question is too broad, here are the special cases i'm especially interested in:

We start with $R=\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$, on the algebra side one may choose $S=M_2(R)$ or the subalgebra of the matrices given by:
\begin{pmatrix}R &R \\ xR &R \end{pmatrix}
and one may choose $N=S$ and $M=S/T$ to be an finite length quotient of $S$, i.e there is a sequence $0\rightarrow T\rightarrow S \rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$. Further more the case $i=2$ would be enough.

So what i'm really interested in is:
Is the map $ Ext_S^2(S/T,S)\rightarrow Ext_R^2(S/T,S)$ injective in these cases?

Inducing injective maps on the $Ext$-groups is, i think, more than being a faithful functor. Maybe this property has already been studied and has its own name? I don't see any sequences which relate these two groups, so that one could see this by doing some kind of diagram chasing.

Any hints or ideas are welcome!

Comment: A map which is *surjective* on Exts is called an *homological epimorphism* (these were studied by Auslander, Platzek and Todorov a while ago). I've never seen the injective variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a map or algebras $R\to S$, a left $R$-module $M$ and a left $S$-module $N$, there is a natural first quadrant, cohomologically graded spectral sequence with $$E_2^{p,q}=\mathrm{Ext}^p_S(\mathrm{Tor}_R^q(S,M),N)$$ converging to $\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(M,N)$.

**If $S$ is flat as a left $R$-module**, this collapses to natural isomorphisms 
$$
\mathrm{Ext}_S^\bullet(S\otimes_RM,N)\cong\mathrm{Ext}^\bullet_R(M,N). \qquad\qquad(\star)
$$

**Suppose now moreover that $S$ is a separable $R$-algebra,** and go to the situation of the question in which both $M$ and $N$ are a left $S$-modules. If $S\otimes_RS\to S$ is the map induced by multiplication in $S$, which is a map of $S$-bimodules, and $\Omega$ is its kernel, we have a short exact sequence of $S$-bimodules $$0\to\Omega\to S\otimes_RS\to S\to 0$$ which splits—this is separability. Tensoring this with $M$ over $S$ gives then a *split* short exact sequence $$0\to\Omega\otimes_SM\to S\otimes_RS\otimes_SM\to S\otimes_SM\to 0$$ which can be identified with $$0\to\Omega\otimes_SM\to S\otimes_RM\to M\to 0.$$ The long exact sequence obtained from it by applying $\mathrm{Ext}_S^\bullet(\mathord-,N)$ splits into little exact sequences $$0\to\mathrm{Ext}_S^p(M,N)\to\mathrm{Ext}_S^p(S\otimes_RM,N)\to \mathrm{Ext}^p_S(\Omega_S\otimes_SM,N)\to 0.$$
In particular, the map $\mathrm{Ext}_S^p(M,N)\to\mathrm{Ext}_S^p(S\otimes_RM,N)$ is injective, so when we compose it with $(\star)$ we get an injection
$$\mathrm{Ext}_S^p(M,N)\to\mathrm{Ext}_R^p(M,N).$$ It is not hard to see that this composition is the map you wanted.

This deals with your matrix algebra.

Comment: Do you need that $M$ is an $S$-module, which becomes an $R$-module after restricting along $R\to S$?

If so, isn't $\Omega\otimes_S M \to S\otimes_R M\to M$ in your context split as well, as a sequence of left $S$-modules? So that $\text{Ext}^2_S(-,N)$, being an additive functor, maps it to a split short exact sequence $\text{Ext}^2_S(\Omega\otimes_S M,N)\leftarrow\text{Ext}^2_S(S\otimes_R M,N)\leftarrow\text{Ext}^2_S(M,N)$, which amounts to the split short exact sequence $\text{Ext}^2_S(\Omega\otimes_S M,N)\leftarrow\text{Ext}^2_R(M,N)\leftarrow\text{Ext}^2_S(M,N)$?

Comment: Matthias, indeed: the first sentence list the requirements for the spectral sequence, for the rest is in the context of the question; I'll edit so asto make it clear. As for your second point, of course!: that gives injectivity (in all degrees).

Comment: Question: If ($S$ is $R$-projective and) the forgetful functor induces injections on Exts, is $S$ not then separable?

Comment: @Mariano: Concerning your question: This is true at least if $S$ is a supplemented $R$-algebra. For, by $R$-projectivity, there is an isomorphism $Ext^n_{S\otimes_R S}(S,N) \cong Ext^n_S(R;N)$ (Cartan-Eilenberg, X, Prop. 1.1) and the latter embedds into $Ext^n_R(R;N)=0$ if $n>0$. In particular  $Ext^1_{S\otimes_R S}(S,N) =0$ and hence $S$ is separable (see Rowen, Ring Theory II, 5.3.7). Thus a supplemented projective $R$-algebra $S$ is separable iff $\operatorname{res}_R^S: Ext_S \to Ext_R$ is injective.  

Comment: Ralph, That was the motivation for the question in the general case, actually :) You should probably copy your comment to an answer to the OP.

Comment: Mariano, the idea that injectivity of res implies separability is yours. I only provided a   marginal technical justification. 

Comment: Thank you Mariano & Ralph. Very good. To use this result i'm still trying to decide whether my second $S$ is separable over $R$ or not. I found that is enough to check if $S/mS$ is a separable $R/m$-algebra. But since $xR\otimes R/m\cong R/m$, $S/mS\cong M_2(R/m)$ which is separable over $R/m$. But then $S$ is a central and separable $R$-algebra, so it is Azumaya. But over $R=\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ all Azumayas should be of the form $M_n(R)$ because the Brauer group vanishes. Where is the mistake in this argument?

Comment: What is the tensor product in $xR \otimes R/m$ taken over ? If over $R$ and $m=(x,y)$, then, isn't the tensor product =0 ? 

Comment: It is $S/mS=S\otimes_R R/m$ so it is over $R$. But the tensor product is not $=0$, i thought so too at first, but since $1\notin xR$, we cannot do things like $x\otimes y=1\otimes xy=1\otimes 0=0$. Looking at the sequence $0\rightarrow m\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/m\rightarrow 0$, and using the fact that $xR$ is a free $R$-module then should give $xR\otimes_R R/m\cong R/m$.

Comment: Indeed, $xR$ is a free $R$-module, so you can replace it up to iso by $R$.

Comment: This is very good. So i can use this result in both cases, and for even more $S$. Thanks a lot for your help guys!